# Particle systems' physics heavily depends on framerate?

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics, frame-rate, particle-system

We are making a 2d game and I stumbled upon some strange behavior.

When I made some particle systems in Unity3d itself, everything was looking right. When I made an application and started it on maximum settings, particles were behaving themselves like crazy. When I started at low settings and they were good.

I found out that it depends on vsync setting (and FPS, as result). Now, without vsync FPS is 1100 (with vsync: 60). Maybe even the whole physics is changing, I haven't spotted that yet.

So the question is: how can I fix this? I can't just turn off the very possibility to turn vsync on, because as I understand, when a game will become more complicated, FPS will drop, and then what? Redo all particle systems? And tearing may appear, why do so?

On the other hand I can't force VSYNC for the following reasons:

- intense difficulties with working in Unity IDE itself (it runs game "preview" without vsync, also, in "scene" mode particles appear as they are without vsync on.)
- The game will be playable at 30-50 FPS, how it will behave with forced vsync? It will turn it off and particles will start to behave weird again? *(UPDATE: the correct answer it will sync to 30 FPS, obviously)*

(No scripts were used in the particle systems' gameobjects, just empty GameObject with system attached).

Comment: What you see is the stability (or instability) of a system depending on the size of the timestep. Depending on the integration used, the stability of the system will depend on the time-delta fed into it to get to the next frame. With a small value (at a high FPS) that will be more stable than at larger steps. And the more stiff your system is, the faster the trouble starts. So it would be interesting to see what exactly you've set up and with what values.

Comment: here you go [balloon expl.png](http://cs617629.vk.me/v617629278/7a66/SmVbcLQ3NBM.jpg)

Comment: it's the baloon explosion. the whole idea is spawn (pretty) big number of particles in little time. then the fly away from center with very high speeds, that are heavily dumped. so particle's initial velocitys get back too 0 soon and only gravity acts, so they fall down slowly. it looks good and i like how it looks, but with framerat of 60 velocities are dumped too slowly (i think), so particles radius instead of just taking ~20% of screen width in normal scenario, fly away much farther and beyond screen borders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in Unity and has been reported previously in their issue tracker. See http://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/shuriken-particle-system-module-limit-velocity-over-lifetime-is-fps-dependent